# Is it possible to check if a Dialog is visible on an activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android app, that has many dialogs that pop up at once. I need to write a check if the activity contains a dialog at that time. I initially used this code:

```
public static boolean hasOpenedDialogs(FragmentActivity activity) {
    List<Fragment> fragments = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment instanceof Dialog) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this only works for dialogfragment, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a singleton for your application and set a flag Enum for example when you show a Dialog, then you verify if that flag is setup that means that you opened a dialog.